# how to limit the number of list's itmes per each screen?

Tags: android-studio

I am new android studio developer.
I am using listView , so I want to limit the items previewed for each screen, for example I want only 6 items only to be shown on screen.
I couldn't find any xml attribute can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you list adapter only add 6 items to it or return 6 for the count of items in the adapter. Just because you pass in a full array you don't have to display every item in the array.

There is a general move away from ListView / ListAdapter to RecyclerView / RecyclerViewAdapter so you many want to consider moving to them as well.